# Is Xcode 7 auto layout broken or just difficult to use

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode7

Since moving to Xcode 7 I am receiving a lot of warnings that I didn't get in Xcode 6 - "Frame for -text field- will be different at run time".

I have followed all of the suggested resolutions based on "Resolve auto layout issues" but that actually breaks the layout that I had established with objects no longer positioned where I want them.  It seems to me to be a bug.

In order to test this I created a new VC and added a label, button and text field.  For the button and label I set constraints to establish the vertical position, then fixed height and width and finally Horizontally centre on container.  This is how I have always used auto layout and it works correctly showing blue constraints and no errors or warnings.  The problem is the text field which I have stretched to the left and right guidelines of the VC.  For this I add vertical, left and right constraints and fixed height and I am left with a warning that - 'Frame for "Round Style Text Field" will be different at run time.'  I'm not doing anything complex here, simply using auto layout they way I have consistently used it in previous versions of Xcode.  So I can only see the following possibilities:

1. Its a bug and not working correctly.  It is tied to an Xcode guideline and yet is 4 units out of position... why?
2. The way I have always used auto layout is no longer supported and I need to use it differently.  When I use reset to suggested constraints it removes the right hand constraint and replaces it with a centre constraint to align with the button above it.  I don't understand how these suggested constraints work and so wouldn't think to do it this way myself.
3. Its no longer possible to apply constraints normally without letting Xcode do it for you?  When I have had problems in the past I have simply cleared constraints and re-applied them and it has always worked.  Now I cannot apply constraints myself successfully even with this very simple test VC!!

I get the impression that most people find auto-layout has problems and as a result very few people are using it, but unless we get to the bottom of problems like this it will just continue.  I am frustrated with what appears to be a arbitrary change to the way auto-layout works.  Before i report as a bug I would like to get views from other people with experience in auto-layout.

Comment: No, it's not a bug, In Your storyboard on the right of Pin Constraint option there is a triangular shape icon. Click on it and you will see an option to "Update Frame". Select each view that complains about changed frame in runtime and update it's frame by clicking on that option.

Comment: Hi Gandalf, thanks for your feedback but the issue I have is if you update frames or constraints or Reset to suggested constraints it changes your layout.  If you have a number of objects on a VC and you have them aligned the way you want them then its no good to have Xcode move something to the left to address what ever it is worried about.  And the point I am making is why has this started happening in Xcode 7 when the same project in Xcode 6 worked fine without warnings.  Once again just seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Using my simple text field example, as I explained I used the standard guideline to stretch the text field to a fixed distance from the edge of the screen which is 20 units but I get a warning that it should be 16!!!! Why should it be 16 units when the standard guideline that my objects snap to is a 20 units??  If I follow your suggestion and Update Frame it stretches the text field by 4 units left and right so it is now 4 units closer to the edge of the screen.  This is just illogical, like Apple have changed the guidelines in the compiler but forgot to change IB.

Comment: Does anyone have any further comments on this, I still don't understand why everyone seems to be accepting this as working correctly?  I will submit as a bug and report back.

Comment: I couldn't make out anything out of your statement __The trouble is Xcode 7 seems to want these to be 16 units from the edge of the view but the guidelines are at 20__. Can you create a basic sample code with __problem un-resolved__ and i may try to answer after looking at it. I have been using AutoLayout from Xcode 6 and now i am on Xcode 7.2 but have never seen a situation i should call a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Interface builder is rather schizophrenic with AutoLayout. It maintains 2 largely independent settings on your views: Their frames, and their constraints. The frames are ignored at runtime and overridden by the constraints.

If the views' frames don't match the frames that would result from applying the constraints, you get the warnings that you are getting.

To fix it, use the editor menu>Resolve Auto Layout Issues>Update Frames. (The "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" commands are also available from the triangle icon, as Gandalf mentions in his comment.)

That adjusts the sizes and positions of your views to match the constraints you've set.

The "reset to suggested constraints" command does the opposite, and discards and replaces your constraints based on (I think) the positions of the views. I have never found this useful. I would say it's best avoided once you've started setting constraints.

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for the feedback but how does this explain the 4 unit offset as per my response to Gandalf and why is this happening in Xcode 7 and not previously.  When you place a text field in a VC that you want to use Auto layout to stretch to the edges of what ever screen its displayed on or if the user switches from portrait to landscape then you need a constraint relative to a point on the VC.  If you stretch to the blue guidelines and then apply left & right constraints the value of that constraint is '0' even though it is 20 units in from the edge of the view.  Continued...

Comment: The actual constraint is "Trailing space to superview" and it is equal to zero and "Leading space to superview" once again zero.  The trouble is Xcode 7 seems to want these to be 16 units from the edge of the view but the guidelines are at 20 and thus it generates a warning but as far as I can tell this warning is an error.  I still can't see how this is not a bug.  Are we not just making excuses for auto-layout that it is so confusing you need to let Xcode correct it every time you add an object because its no longer possible to add something without getting a warning?

Comment: Autolayout is very difficult to understand